# How can I sync three classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop

```
class Foo
{
    Bar b;
    List<Foo> Neighbours;
}

class Bar
{
    Spam s;
    List<Bar> Neighbours;
}

class Spam
{
    List<string> Neighbours; 
}
```

Each of these classes have `AddNeighbour`,`RemoveNeighbour` methods.

**User can add/remove Neighbours from any of the class at random.**

I want these three objects to be in **sync**.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Can you give more info on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @UpTheCreek There are three graphs I need to sync. They have basic structure similar to shown above.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect if one adds a `string` neighbour to `Spam`? How do the `Foo` and `Bar` objects look like that have to be created then?

Comment: Hmm I just saw you are referencing the corresponding `Spam` in your `Bar` and same with `Foo` and `Bar`. So I guess you dont want anyone to add a `Foo` or `Spam`?

Comment: What is the reason for seperating them at all? Sure you have a good reason. Proxy pattern? is `Spam` in a sealed library?

Comment: Thanks @ Philip Daubmeier for enthusiasm !! :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option one - Have Foo call Bar when it's updated and Bar call Spam.  This will lead to tightly coupled objects and you'll probably also need to have Spam call back to Bar which calls back to Foo to sync in the other direction, yuk.

Option two - Have a class that observes each of the three objects and updates the others when one changes. (External synchroniser)

Option three - Revise the design and store the data in ONE class and implement three interfaces that return the data as either a List<Bar>, List<Foo> or List<string>.  That way you can choose to store the data once (and convert as requested) or keep the object's three internal lists in sync more easily.

Option four - Have a common data model that is updated and each object observes that and syncs it's own internal list from the data model

**EDIT** - Following your comment that this is for three graphs, the observer pattern is probably the best way to do this.  Have a single common data model that each are observing and adapting to the specific type required by the graph its serving.

Comment: definitely would take option three or four. To make the observation of the common list a little easier you could take there a `BindingList<T>` and the observer(s) would easily be notified about any change within the underlying list.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

You could have each object register itself with the Observer,
when any object changes it notifies the Observer, which then updates all other subscribers.

HTH